# Inline BASH variable, can't get the command to receive it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why doesn't this work?

`HELLO=WORLD echo $HELLO`

In my shell it outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that bash is evaluating and replacing `$HELLO` *before* your command executes. If you write a script like:

```
echo $HELLO
```

and run `HELLO=WORLD ./script`, you will see the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

That command sets `HELLO` to the string `WORLD` only in the environment of `echo`.  But `echo` ignores that environment variable and merely writes its arguments and a newline.  In the shell, (presumably) the variable HELLO is not set at all, so `echo` just prints a single newline.

Perhaps you want:

```
HELLO=WORLD; echo "$HELLO"
```

which is two separate commands.  The first sets `HELLO` in the shell, and the second passes that value as an argument to `echo`.